# Django ImportError on Heroku

Tags: django, heroku

I tried several things to get my app working on heroku, but now I'm out of ideas. I can install my project on heroku's rep, but I get a 500 error code. My application works very well using virtualenv on my machine after I followed the steps described on heroku documentation for django.

When I do my "git push heroku master" and try in browser, I get the following error:

```
2013-07-07T15:39:11.170514+00:00 app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named apps.base
2013-07-07T15:39:11.170059+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateformat.py", line 35, in format
2013-07-07T15:39:11.170202+00:00 app[web.1]:     app = import_module(appname)
2013-07-07T15:39:11.170202+00:00 app[web.1]:     default_translation = _fetch(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
2013-07-07T15:39:11.170202+00:00 app[web.1]:     _default = translation(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)
```

I tought it was caused by a directory structure that wasn't supported on heroku, so I adjusted it from the default one that was created with django startproject command.

Here is my new file structure. I adjusted the import reference everywhere and as I said, I works pefctly in local:

```
manage.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
vielfaltig
|____apps
| |____base
| | |____models.py
| | |____templates
| | |____tests.py
| | |____urls.py
| | |____views.py
| |____projects
| | |____admin.py
| | |____models.py
| | |____templates
| | |____templatetags
| | |____tests.py
| | |____translation.py
| | |____urls.py
| | |____views.py
|____locale
|____media
|____settings.py
|____static
|____urls.py
|____vielfaltig.db
|____wsgi.py
```

As you notice, I have 2 apps (base and projects). In the code, I import them using "vielfaltig.apps.base" for example. I changed this everywhere. I had this error before and I changed the directory structure according to what I read when I googled the error. I also tried to put everything in the root directory (along with the requirements.txt and procfile). I don't know why it keeps telling me an ImportError for "apps.base" while I reference the app using "vielfaltif.apps.base" everywhere... ?

Does anyone have an idea? I will paste my settings.py if needed. For now I think it would just take a lot of space.

Thank you very much for any help !

Answer (score 0):

I guess it will work with `import vielfaltig.apps.base` instead of `apps.base`. It can be fixed if you insert path `vielfaltig` to python system path in your `settings.py`

```
import sys

sys.path.append('vielfaltig')
```

Comment: It can be done like: `import sys; sys.path.insert(0, 'vielfaltig')` in a to of `settings.py`.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I need to do this because I already changed all my imports to "import vielfaltig.apps.base" in all my files where it applied. Also, it works very well in locale. Still I have tried your suggestion and I doesn't work... the server isn't even starting with that change. I think the problem is somewhere else, maybe in translations ? But I checked my translations files and the paths seems ok...

Comment: Try `python manage.py` without any flags and I think it will throw you an exception. If it does please write it in your question.